# How do I write a function which behaves differently depending on which monad is at the base of the transformer stack

Tags: haskell

(At this point this is more of a puzzle I'd like know how to solve than a solution I expect to use in practice)

I'm trying to write a function `runDebug` with the following specification: its argument has type `IO ()`; its return type is `(Monad m) => m ()`; depending on `m`, it behaves in one of two different ways; if `MonadIO m`, then `runDebug = liftIO`, and otherwise `runDebug = const (return ())`.

The approaches I've tried relied on a type class like

```
class MonadDebug m where
  runDebug :: IO () -> m ()
```

I've tried using `MonadBase`, and I've tried using `MonadIO` with overlapping instances, but all of them have run into issues with ambiguity.

I think I could get something that works by writing instances for each transformer, but I've been hoping to avoid that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Write instances of `MonadDebug` for each transformer and each base monad that you are interested in supporting.

Comment: That's what I'm hoping to avoid, if possible (see the last line of the question).

Comment: @AlexR See [Real World Haskell](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/monad-transformers.html) on how this is the current best solution.  It isn't pretty, I agree, but it's just how you have to do it with mtl.

Comment: @AlexR I saw the last line of the question. I practically quoted it, and on purpose.

Comment: @bheklilr, mtl and transformers are different packages (the former building upon the latter); I'm hoping that between the extensions in GHC 7.10 and packages like monad-classes, there's something that I can piggy-back off of, even if I wouldn't want to use it in production code.

Comment: @DanielWagner, :( I don't like your answer (but I did upvote it). I'll accept it if nothing more palatable comes up.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, as soon as I post to SO, I figure out how to get what I want.

As far as I can tell, the following code solves my problem:

```
class (Monad m) => MonadDebug m where
  runDebug :: IO () -> m ()

instance MonadDebug Identity where
  runDebug _ = return ()

instance MonadDebug IO where
  runDebug m = m

instance (Monad (t m), MonadTrans t, MonadDebug m) => MonadDebug (t m) where
  runDebug m = lift $ runDebug m
```

Comment: This sort of works, until you want to support something like [`Free`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/free-4.12.1/docs/Control-Monad-Free.html) or [`Prompt`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/MonadPrompt-1.0.0.5/docs/Control-Monad-Prompt.html) that fit the shape of your last instance, but only by accident.

Comment: I don't see how those would break.

Comment: They are not monad transformers (hence not instances of `MonadTrans`).

Comment: The docs beg to differ (at least for `free`): [link](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/free-4.12.1/docs/src/Control-Monad-Free.html#line-212)

Comment: As mentioned in the docs, it is not a real monad transformer (it requires some equations to hold); and even if it were, `Free f` is a monad even when `f` isn't (and thus the `Monad (Free f)` constraint in your head wouldn't hold).